# Declaring and defining class static member variable does not result in multiple declaration, why is this?

Tags: c++

I would like to know why declaring a static variable and then defining it in a source file not cause a multiple declaration compiler error. Below is a trivial example of what I mean.

```
// header.hpp
class Foo
{
public:
static int my_var; // declare
};
// source.cpp
#include "header.hpp"
int Foo::my_var = 5; // define
```

Why does my_var not cause a multiple declaration compiler error?

Also, would the following example code not cause an error for the same reason as above?

```
// Class.hpp
class Foo
{
...
};

#include "Class.hpp"
class Foo; // Forward declare, no multiple declaration?
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why did you use `static` instead of `extern`?

Comment: Just wanted to create the most simple example as possible. Sorry if it doesn't make sense but I just wanted to get across the point that I am mainly confused about the fact that it looks likes a multiple declaration problem.

Comment: The first block of code should cause a compiler error. See a trivial example at https://ideone.com/vBwCSa. The second block of code is legal.

Comment: ...unlike `extern`, which would compile.

Comment: Sorry, just updated the example to use a class. Should compile now.

Comment: @RSahu Could you elaborate on why the second example is illegal? I thought that is a valid way to forward declare a class.

Comment: I said legal, not illegal.

Comment: Also, in the second snippet `class Foo {...};` is a definition and `class Foo;` is a declaration (not the other way around).

Comment: The edit completely changes the question. The original code was wrong and the current code is correct

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. So I guess I thought the above examples were synonymous to `int x;` then doing `int x = 5`

Comment: @Tagger5926 Those would be duplicate *definitions*. Duplicate declarations are normally allowed.

Comment: Okay, it's starting to make sense. Thanks. I should probably look deeper into what static and extern actual mean. I always thought `int x` was just declaring x. My bad...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you pointed out,

```
static int my_var; // declare
```

is a declaration. It is a declaration of the `static` membr variable of the class.

and

```
int Foo::my_var = 5; // define
```

is the definition of the `static` member variable of the class. There is no reason that should be an error.

---

As to

```
class Foo
{
...
};

#include "Class.hpp"
class Foo;
```

That is perfectly fine.

You can declare a name, in this case a class, as many times as you want as long as there is no conflict.

The language is quite flexible for declarations.

You can use:

```
class Foo { ... };

class Foo;
class Foo;
class Foo;
class Foo;
class Foo;
class Foo;
class Foo;
```

without any problem.

You may even use:

```
class Foo { ... };

int Foo;
```

as long as you are careful with your use of `Foo` the `class` and `Foo` the variable.

```
int main()
{
   class Foo f1; // OK. f1 is of type class Foo
   Foo = 10;     // OK. Foo is the variable.
   Foo f2;       // Not OK. Foo is the variable not the class
}
```

Comment: Yeah I guess I will have to look more into the typing system for c++. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating the class, you state (declare) that there is a member variable. Later you can change its value to be whatever you like (define) (explicitly like in your example or through a function) in whatever part of your code.
Declaring a variable just warns the compiler that a certain variable will be used, and later you can choose whether to give it a value or not.
Because you define it as static, all objects of the class are going to share the same value for this variable.
It is considered good practice in general to define/initialize your static variables when you declare them, otherwise (even if you don't cause a compiler error), your code may nit work as expected.